# Execute one backend calls in sequence with retries in Angular with RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have some Javascript code that deletes documents from a database with API calls. There are internal dependencies between the documents, so a delete may fail. So the code will try to delete all documents in 5 rounds.

But since I am on Angular and uses RxJs for all other task, it would have been nice with an RxJs solution and not async/await and promises. I have manages to get delete one round with concatMap, but how to get the retries in place?

```
private async deleteDocuments(documents: IDocument[]) {
    let retries = 5;
    let remaining = [...documents];
    while (remaining.length > 0 && retries > 0) {
        remaining = await this.deleteDocumentsOneTry(remaining);
        retries--;
    }
}

private async deleteDocumentsOneTry(documents: IDocument[]) {
    const remaining: IDocument[] = [];
    for (const document of documents) {
        const deleted = await this.deleteDocument(document);
        if (deleted) {
            this.documentsDeleted++; // For progress bar
        } else {
            remaining.push(document);
        }
    }

    return remaining;
}

private deleteDocument(document: IDocument) {
    console.log(`Delete document ${document.name}`);
    return this.backend
        .deleteDocuments(document.id)
        .pipe(
            map(() => true),
            catchError(() => of(false))
        )
        .toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing it as demonstrated below:

```
return from(documents).pipe(
  mergeScan((failed: number, document: IDocument) => {
    return that.backend.deleteDocuments(document.id).pipe(
      tap(x => this.documentsDeleted++),
      mapTo(failed),
      catchError((error, source) => failed < 5 ? source.pipe(mapTo(++failed)) : throwError(error))
    )
  }, 0)
)
```

Simplified implementation:

```
let retries = 5;

from(documents).pipe(
  concatMap(doc => that.backend.deleteDocuments(doc.id).pipe(
    catchError((error, source) => --retries > 0 ? source : throwError(error)),
  ))
).subscribe((x) => this.documentsDeleted++)
```